# .NET 5 ClickOnce creates duplicate deployment in PublishDir

Tags: .net, msbuild, clickonce

I'm using `msbuild` (version 17.1.0+ae57d105c, from a VS 2022 Developer Command Prompt) to publish a ClickOnce .NET 5 application to a UNC path using the commandline. As such, I'm running what amounts to

```
>msbuild /t:publish -p:PublishProfile=.\Properties\PublishProfiles\ClickOnceProfile.pubxml /p:PublishDir=\\some\unc\path\
```

As expected, this moves a lot of files to `\\some\unc\path`. If I did this prior to .NET 5, I would generally expect to files like

```
\\some\unc\path\setup.exe
\\some\unc\path\Application Files\MyApp_1_0_0_9\SomeLibrary.dll.deploy
```

but if I use the command above, or if I publish from Visual Studio, I also get a bunch of files in the root of `PublishDir`,

```
\\some\unc\path\SomeLibrary.dll
```

Given that this didn't happen in earlier versions, I'm assuming these files are redundant, and that they're just noise. But why are they created? Can I get rid of them?

Comment: Cf. [the comment here](https://github.com/dotnet/deployment-tools/issues/198#issuecomment-1111432741), this is a [well-known problem](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Clickonce-for-NET-Core-issues/1500772).

Answer (score 0):

In my experience this is a bug which occurs when you set `<PublishDir>` and `<PublishUrl>` to the same value in your .pubxml profile. Which seems like a reasonable thing to do, since according to [these docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/building-clickonce-applications-from-the-command-line?view=vs-2022)

> PublishUrl is the location where the application will be published to in the IDE.

and

> The MSBuild system uses the PublishDir option to specify the location for output

That makes it sound like you should set both tags if you want to publish both from within VS and from the command line. However if you do set them both to the same value, you get all the duplicate files. If I set `<PublishDir>` to some random temporary directory, I no longer get the duplicate files when hitting the Publish button in VS.

I've raised this with Microsoft [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Clickonce-for-NET-Core-issues/1500772#TPIN-N10194184-N10253874).